# Change PHP variable using javascript or AJAX on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xhtml

I know this question has been asked alot of times, but I think in my case, I'm dealing with something different, or better saying, I need something different.

I'm using an open source that works as appointments booking but unfortunately, the client can choose the service and not the duration of it. I can recreate the same service by manually adding it more times with different minutes length but that way, in the dropdown menu, would be present alot of options and that's not what I'm looking for as a workaround.

So, what I thought of, was using a dropdown to select the time, and based on that selection, on the services dropdown menu, would show the ONLY the corresponding ones based on time.
THe site looks like this:
[site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tlh6.png)

What I'm looking for, is that whenever I select the nr of hours... I ONLY GET the services that are part of that hour and not all of them.
I'm ok with using a button that refreshes the page as far as that works, but I can't create another file that then redirects here.

This is the part of the code interested in that:

```
<select id="select-service" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control">

<?php
    // Group services by category, only if there is at least one service with a parent category.
    $has_category = FALSE;
    foreach($available_services as $service) {
        if ($service['category_id'] != NULL) {
            $has_category = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($has_category) {
        $grouped_services = array();

        foreach($available_services as $service) {
            if ($service['category_name'] == '2 HOURS' || $service['category_name'] == '1 HOUR' || $service['category_name'] == '3 HOURS') {
                if (!isset($grouped_services[$service['category_name']])) {
                    $grouped_services[$service['category_name']] = array();
                }

                $grouped_services[$service['category_name']][] = $service;
            }

        }

        // We need the uncategorized services at the end of the list so
        // we will use another iteration only for the uncategorized services.
        $grouped_services['uncategorized'] = array();
        foreach($available_services as $service) {
            if ($service['category_id'] == NULL) {
                $grouped_services['uncategorized'][] = $service;
            }
        }

        foreach($grouped_services as $key => $group) {
            $group_label = ($key != 'uncategorized')
                    ? $group[0]['category_name'] : 'Uncategorized';

            if (count($group) > 0) {
                echo '<optgroup label="' . $group_label . '">';
                foreach($group as $service) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $service['id'] . '">'
                        . $service['name'] . '</option>';
                }
                echo '</optgroup>';
            }
        }
    }  else {
        foreach($available_services as $service) {
            echo '<option value="' . $service['id'] . '">' . $service['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only use a single AJAX function for my platform. Below is a minimal example:

```
function ajax(method,url,param_id_container_pos,id_container)
{
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open(method,url,true);

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  if (xhr.readyState=='4')
  {
   var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type').split('/')[1];
   if (method=='post')
   {
    if (type=='json')
    {
     var j = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     console.log(j);//Check your browser's developer network panel.
     eval(j.javascript);//eval is frowned upon though just use to call a sequel JS function.
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

//Example uses:
ajax('get','admin/?ajax=account','inside','id_target');

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('ajax','admin_post_account_approval');
fd.append('parameter1',object1);
fd.append('parameter2',object2);
ajax('post',path+'admin/',fd);
```

Your goal is to make your code minimal and *highly* reusable when possible.

In regards to the server and PHP you need to remember: *never trust the user*. That means you need to verify everything:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']=='admin_post_account_approval')
{
 if (!isset($_POST['parameter1'])) {/*error_handling*/}
 else if (!isset($_POST['parameter1'])) {/*error_handling*/}
 else if (![condition not met]) {}
 else
 {
  if ([all conditions met])
  {
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $array = array('javascript'=>'alert(\'Just a JavaScript alert triggered by PHP.\');');
   die(json_encode($array));
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Server side code, PHP should be thought of like real life: always fail *first* and test the conditions for length, proper characters or improper characters in form parameters, etc.

Additionally I highly recommend having the server respond with JSON as I generally illustrated in the code above. Because I only write my own code and don't work with other people's code this is more of a generic response than attempting to target whatever software you're working with. Regardless if you enable error reporting and pay attention to your developer tools in whichever browser you're using you'll get there. Good luck.